# How to start developing for Ubuntu

Tags: programming

I would like to learn how to develop a multi-clipboard application for Unity, similar to Diodon, for learning purposes.

Can you give me a link or some direction to get started?

I have generic programming skills but I think I can do it! :D

Hope you can help and that I'm not off topic.

Comment: You may want to start here: [Ubuntu Developer](http://developer.ubuntu.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find this video useful: [Creating Your First Ubuntu App](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sO8hiPreNBg). Enjoy!